# Doesn't the length of the array get validated at run time at VC++?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++

When i run the program to get 5th element from the array  which has a size 4 only i get junk value instead of array out of bound exception. Doesn't the length of the array get validated at run time at VC++?

Comment: No, it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: If you want this kind of run-time checking (and it's associated performance costs) then you'll need to use a higher level language than C or C++.

Comment: If you want run time checks. Use std::vector<> not raw arrays. Then the method `at()` gives run time checks to make sure it is in bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ has arrays with bound checking, but not using `[]`. `std::array<T, N>::at(i)` will check that `0 <= i < N`, and throw a `std::out_of_range` exception.

`std::vector<T>` is a variable-length equivalent of an array, and offers the same `at()` method. This of course uses the current vector length, not a hardcoded `N`.

Answer (score 6):

In C++, reading off the end of an array results in *undefined behavior*, which means that pretty much anything can happen - you might get garbage, you might get valid data, you might trigger a debug assertion or exception, etc.  However, you shouldn't rely on anything in particular to happen.  One of the challenges of using C++ is learning to check your array indices, as it's pretty much a fact of life in C++ that the language won't do it for you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's not that common to check array indices anymore. `for (auto& element : array)` automatically stops at the end of the array.

Answer (score 4):

Ordinary arrays do not perform bounds checking.  If you want that, use a `std::vector` instead.  Its `[]` operator does not perform bounds checking, but its `at()` method does, throwing an `std::out_of_range` exception when an invalid index is accessed.

Answer (score 2):

VC++ is one product that implements C and C++. The programming languages does not define any bounds checking and the compiler doesn't implement it. When you access memory off the bounds you access *something* what's undefined behavior.

Comment: In fact, VC++ is only a C++ compiler. Of course, this means that a lot of C code can also be compiled with it, but it does not include any C specific feature at all, and it has no "C mode" to compile only valid C code.

Comment: @Gorpik: That is totally false.  To compile in C mode, use the `/TC` flag, or name your files with `.c` extensions.  In C mode, the compiler can compile C code that is not legal C++ code, and it produces object files that do not have C++ features like name mangling.  There really are two different compilers down in there!

Comment: @librik Really? I stand corrected then. I must admit that I had not been following that, but last I remember there was no C compiler and no plans to include it.

Comment: There has always been a C compiler, since before there was a C++ compiler.  There is no C99 support in that C compiler -- it's ANSI C (89) only -- and no plans to include it.  The C99 issue is what you're vaguely remembering.  (The very latest release is supposed to have some C99 stuff, at least the stuff everybody uses, but it's not a full implementation.)